# Web Scraping with VBA

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I wrote this to scrape album review data from [AOTY](http://albumoftheyear.org) into a spreadsheet. Check it out and let me know what I could've done better.

```
Option Explicit

Const classAlbum As String = "listLargeTitle"
Const classScore As String = "listScoreContainer"
Const classRating As String = "listScoreValueContainer"
Const classReview As String = "listScoreText"
Const classNext As String = "pageSelect"

Sub ScrapeAOTY()

    Dim IE As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLBody As MSHTML.HTMLBody
    Dim Albums As Object
    Dim Ratings As Object
    Dim Reviews As Object
    Dim MetaData As Object
    Dim InnerMeta As Object
    Dim nextPage As Object
    Dim selection As Object
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim aotyYear As String
    Dim url As String
    Dim bookmark As String
    Dim album As String
    Dim review As String
    Dim releaseDate As String
    Dim genre As String
    Dim test As String
    Dim rating As Double
    Dim index As Long
    Dim row As Long
    Dim page As Long
    Dim pageLoading As Boolean
    Dim exitFlag As Boolean

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    aotyYear = InputBox("Input the year you're scraping")
    If aotyYear < 1900 Then Exit Sub
    url = "http://www.albumoftheyear.org/ratings/6-highest-rated/" & aotyYear & "/1"
    Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ScrapeSheet")
    row = 2
    exitFlag = False
    page = 1

    Do
        Set IE = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
        url = "http://www.albumoftheyear.org/ratings/6-highest-rated/" & aotyYear & "/" & page
        IE.Open "GET", url, False
        IE.send

        Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set HTMLDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        Set HTMLBody = HTMLDoc.body
        HTMLBody.innerHTML = IE.responseText
        Set Albums = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName(classAlbum)
        Set Ratings = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName(classRating)
        Set Reviews = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName(classReview)
        Set MetaData = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName(classScore)

        For index = 0 To Albums.Length - 1
            Set InnerMeta = MetaData(index).parentElement.parentElement
            Set InnerMeta = InnerMeta.getElementsByTagName("div")

            album = Albums(index).innerText
            rating = CDbl(Ratings(index).getAttribute("title"))
            review = Reviews(index).innerText
            releaseDate = InnerMeta(0).innerText

            If InnerMeta.Length < 10 Then
                genre = ""
            Else
                genre = InnerMeta(1).innerText
            End If

            sheet.Cells(row, 1) = Mid(album, InStr(1, album, " ") + 1, InStr(1, album, " - ") - InStr(1, album, ".") - 2)
            sheet.Cells(row, 2) = Right(album, Len(album) - InStr(1, album, " - ") - 2)
            sheet.Cells(row, 3) = rating
            sheet.Cells(row, 4) = Left(review, Len(review) - 8)
            sheet.Cells(row, 5) = releaseDate
            sheet.Cells(row, 6) = genre

            row = row + 1
        Next index

        Set nextPage = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName(classNext)

        If nextPage.Length = 2 _
        Or nextPage(0).innerText = "Next >" Then
            page = page + 1
        Else
            exitFlag = True
        End If

        Set IE = Nothing
    Loop Until exitFlag = True

    MsgBox ("Done!")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: I wouldn't name a variable "sheet" or "selection"

Answer (score 8):

I can only point out cosmetic issues (I don't know sqat about VBA),
I hope another reviewer will pass by and cover other aspects.

#### Unused variables

These variables seem to be unused, so why not remove them:

```
Dim selection As Object
Dim bookmark As String
Dim test As String
Dim pageLoading As Boolean
```

#### Magic string

This string appears twice:

> ```
> "http://www.albumoftheyear.org/ratings/6-highest-rated/"
> ```

It would be better to define it one place, so you can change it one place if needed.

#### Readability

This block:

> ```
> aotyYear = InputBox("Input the year you're scraping")
> If aotyYear < 1900 Then Exit Sub
> url = "http://www.albumoftheyear.org/ratings/6-highest-rated/" & aotyYear & "/1"
> Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ScrapeSheet")
> row = 2
> exitFlag = False
> page = 1
> ```

Would be more readable if you break a line after the early return:

```
aotyYear = InputBox("Input the year you're scraping")
If aotyYear < 1900 Then Exit Sub

url = "http://www.albumoftheyear.org/ratings/6-highest-rated/" & aotyYear & "/1"
Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ScrapeSheet")
row = 2
exitFlag = False
page = 1
```

---

It might be a matter of taste,
but I think this would be more readable if the condition was not split,
on a single line.

> ```
>     If nextPage.Length = 2 _
>     Or nextPage(0).innerText = "Next >" Then
>         page = page + 1
>     Else
>         exitFlag = True
>     End If
> ```

Comment: Good catch with the unused/unassigned variables - the only thing Rubberduck picks up that you didn't (apart from a false positive with `sheet` being reported as *not used*), is that the `ScrapeAOTY` member is implicitly public. Note that the `selection` local variable hides the `Selection` object defined by the Excel object model. Nice answer!

Answer (score 6):

First off, I just want to say that's a pretty solid program there. Compared to most reviews I do, most of these points are fairly minor. That said, let's begin.

---

**Naming**

Don't **ever** use protected names for your variables. Protected names are names that are already used by the VBA object model, such as `selection` or `sheet`. They can and will cause chaos and confusion down the road, not to mention the mistakes the compiler might make if it gets confused.

Your naming is not consistent. Some variables have leading capitals, some do not.

The general convention for VBA is:

`camelCase` for procedure-Level Variables
`PascalCase` for Module and Global-Level variables
`SHOUTY_SNAKE_CASE` for constants

you don't have to use these specifically, so long as you do pick a convention and **apply it consistently**.

Other than that, there are a couple of variable names that could be even clearer, but your naming is pretty solid. The variables I think could be clearer: `pageLoading` --> `pageIsLoading`, `page` --> `pageNum`, `IE` to something **much** clearer. I know, it's obvious here what it is, but variable names should **always** be able to stand on their own without additional context.

---

**Other bits and pieces**

I personally prefer to put my loop conditions at the start of my loops rather than the end. The end can be much easier to miss and this way, it means you know what to look out for while you're reading through it.

You may want to dim similar variables on the same line to make it less wall-of-text-like. Like so:

```
dim albums as object, ratings as object, reviews as object
```

Comment: Good points, but determining where to put the condition on a loop very much comes down to how you want to use it. A loop that you know you want to run 1+ times, is naturally checked at the end. For loops that run 0+ times a check initially is natural. Since the OPs code actually determines whether or not to continue based upon data obtained within the loop a check at the end makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

All the major things that can be changed to give your scraper a better look have already been pointed out. However, few things you should take into consideration:

1. It doesn't require to use the same `Link` more than once; rather, put it in a variable and reuse it.
2. If any number given in the InputBox is greater than 2017 then it will fail miserably or give the wrong results. Moreover, if anyone runs your code and decides instantly to quit or any bad data is given or `OK` button is pressed without feeding anything to the InputBox then it will throw error.
3. You don't need to use `Do Loop` here because the `For Loop` is sufficient to accomplish the task.
4. You didn't make your scraper in such a way so that it can handle errors if any data is missing.
5. And lastly, how about creating a header? If your scraper is made to run the headers will always be there.

Implementing all the things I've said here, your parser can get a different appearance like below:

```
Sub Aoty_Scraper()

    Const main_link As String = "http://www.albumoftheyear.org/ratings/6-highest-rated/"
    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument, htm As New HTMLDocument
    Dim post As HTMLHtmlElement, page As Object, next_page As String
    Dim row As Long, inputyear As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    inputyear = InputBox("Input any year between 1900 and this year")
    If inputyear < 1900 Or inputyear > 2017 Then Exit Sub

    [A1:D1] = [{"Album/Singer","Title","Score","Review"}]

    With http
        .Open "GET", main_link & inputyear & "/1", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    For Each page In html.getElementsByClassName("smallBottomLink")
        next_page = page.innerText

        With http
            .Open "GET", main_link & inputyear & "/" & next_page, False
            .send
            htm.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With

        For Each post In htm.getElementsByClassName("albumListRow")
            With post.getElementsByClassName("listLargeTitle")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")
                If .Length Then row = row + 1: Cells(row + 1, 1) = Split(.item(0).innerText, "-")(0)
            End With
            With post.getElementsByClassName("listLargeTitle")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")
                If .Length Then Cells(row + 1, 2) = Split(.item(0).innerText, "-")(1)
            End With
            With post.getElementsByClassName("listScoreValue")
                If .Length Then Cells(row + 1, 3) = .item(0).innerText
            End With
            With post.getElementsByClassName("listScoreText")
                If .Length Then Cells(row + 1, 4) = Split(.item(0).innerText, " ")(0)
            End With
        Next post

    Next page

    MsgBox "It's done"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```